# ROWS(INDEX()) or COLUMNS(INDEX()) bug in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

If I enter the following as an array formula in a cell (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER)

`=ROWS(INDEX($A$1:$A$2,{1;2}))`

the value returned is `1`, whereas the expected value is `2`.
Is this a bug in Microsoft excel? I checked that the value returned is `2` in openoffice calc.

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes in the evaluation of `{1;2}`

Assuming other things are equal, it seems that Open Office evaluates this to be 0, while Excel evaluates this to be 1.

If you substitute those values instead of the **{1;2}** you will see the different results:
0 in excel return your expected value of 2
1 returns your observed value of 1

Comment: {1;2} is NOT evaluated as 0 in openoffice. {1;2} implies the rows 1 and 2, whereas 0 implies all the rows. The difference is noted if the reference given in index is $A$1:$A$3, in which case the return value is still 2, whereas replacing {1,2} by 0 returns 3.

Comment: Excel does not evaluate {1;2} as 1. Because, if I select 2 rows and enter the array formula, =INDEX($A$1:$A$3,{1;2}), then I get the values from A1 and A2 in the selected rows correctly.